# How to answer -だね question?

Tags: particles, politeness

So I've come to learn that something + だね means something along the lines of "Is it *_*_?" with an expected yes answer. I received this kind of comment as a response to a photo I posted on the internet. What are some common/friendly ways to respond to this?

Comment: That all depends on how you *want* to answer it.

Comment: In spoken language, one often uses うん、そうだね. On the internet, this feels a bit too content-deprived. To give "common/friendly ways to respond" maybe you can give (or make up) some context, i.e. provide a full sentence that ends in ～だね. If the comment was only "だね", then I think no response is needed, but only shows agreement on part of the commenter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. Any answer would depend on the exactly question being asked as そうだね isn't really appropriate for everything and it's a lame answer, but anything else would depend on context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think ね is sort of rhetorical, and I'd only answer it if I was talking to someone in person. Even then, the answer would probably be something perfunctory like そうだ, just to feign attentiveness ;)

I could be wrong; I learned this from [Tae Kim](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/adverbs), so you can check out that reference and see if it helps. Also, the example sentences at [Tangorin](http://tangorin.com/examples/%E3%81%AD) and Jim Breen's WWWJDIC come off as making it sound rhetorical/for flavor, in the same category as よ and ざ.

Comment: What is ざ? ....

Comment: そうだ sounds pretty curt.

Comment: @Earthling Oops, I meant ぞ.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya I'm really not the best at politeness. This may have been the wrong question for someone like me to answer...

Answer (score 6):

I think it would depend on the context. For example, if someone commented to my photo:

> これ、プードルだね。It's a poodle, right? 
>   インドカレーだね。It's Indian curry, isn't it? 
>   あ、ディズニーランド(に行ったん)だね！Ah you've been to Disneyland?

then I would respond:

> うん！/はい！/ そうよ。/ そうだよ。Yes.
>   そうよ、かわいいでしょ。Yes, isn't it cute? 
>   はい、おいしかったです！Yes, it was yummy! 
>   うん。楽しかったよ。Yes, I had so much fun. etc...

If someone commented:

> オシャレ/ステキだね。It's so fashionable/cool.
>   ハンサム/イケメン/美人だね。You look so handsome/pretty.
>   かわいいプードルだね。Your poodle is so cute! 
>   かっこいい車だね。What a nice car! 
>   (to the food I prepared) おいしそうなカレーだね。Your curry looks yummy.
>   etc...

then I would respond like:

> そう？ありがとう！/ ほんと？ありがとう！^^ Really? Thank you!

If someone said:

> そっくりだね。You two look so alike.
>   珍しい花だね。It's an exotic flower, isn't it.
>  
>   変な動物だね。It's a strange animal, isn't it.

then I would say

> そうでしょ。/ そうね。(feminine) / そうだね。(masculine) Yes, I know. 
>   そう？Oh really?

etc etc...

Comment: A:[美味]{うま}草{そう}～　　B:[草]{そう}[種]{だね}、一緒に食べよう！

Comment: [馬]{うま}[烏賊]{いか}～　[馬]{うま}い[象]{ぞう}～　・・・何のゲーム？

Comment: リアクションに悩むわ、このやり取り・・

Comment: @TokyoNagoya [01414]{おいしいよ}~ [1442]{いっしょに} [91780]{くいなはれ}.

Answer (score 2):

You're right about the expected "yes" answer. 「～だね。」 is a rhetorical question, and a full answer is not expected. ね is a sentence ending particle that changes a statement into a rhetorical question. だ is the casual copula used with nouns or な-adjectives.

The asker is usually mentioning something they think (subjectively) and they expect you to agree with their thoughts. Answering with「うん、そう」 or even simply 「そう」 would work as a general answer.

*As mentioned in the comments below, 「そう」is unnatural as a response to a compliment. In that case you can use 「そうだね」（そうですね）to agree without sounding too arrogant.

It is also common to respond by repeating the statement asked. For example:

Ａさん：今日は寒いね。 (Today is cold, isn't it?)

Ｂさん：うん、寒い。(Yes, it is cold.)

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to comment, so I attempted a full answer.
This answer comes from my limited experience, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 「あっ、そう」「うん、そう」 「そう」

They seem pretty provocative for those who appreciate your photos. そうですね is safer. (Sorry for off topic, but you don't need 。 before 」)

Comment: I think it's okay to put a 。 before a 」... 「～～だね」「～～だね。」「そうだね」「そうだね。」--- 別にどっちでも。。。

Answer (score 1):

For a male speaker, if you're in a casual setting and just want to agree and keep the conversation going: だよなぁ〜。